# What is the difference between a closed figure with two radii and an unclosed figure?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I have been trying to learn Inkscape and I encountered a property of the ellipse tool which said closed figure with two radii. I am very confused about it and cannot make out why it doesn't qualify as an unclosed figure.

[image: This is how they look in inkscape]

Answer (score 8):

In Inkscape, an ellipse created with the Ellipse tool, and the *Switch to Segment* option, is a closed shape.

You will see this if you stroke the shape or if you turn it into paths using *Path > Object to Path*.  It's quite clearly a closed shape.

Ellipse (segment) with stroke.

[image]

Same shape converted to paths.

[image]

Unclosed shapes on the other hand, have a start and end point that do not join up.

For example, this open path was created by switching to the Arc (unclosed shape) option in the Ellipse tool. Then I converted the object to paths so you can see it.

[image]